# Последовательность выполнения директив конфигурационного файла nginx

Tags: nginx

К примеру у меня есть конструкция наподобии этой:

```
location /alpha {
  if (...) {
    ...
  }

  location /alpha/bravo {
    ...
  }
}
```

Должен ли сначала выполниться блок `if`, или вложенный `location`, или порядок выполнения не определен?

Comment: if выполнится, но он делает? лучше if заменить на map и всё станет ровно.

Comment: @nörbörnën вы ж даже не знаете что `if` делает, но пишите что его нужно заменить на map... И что значит "станет ровно"? И вопрос вообще не в том, выполниться ли `if`, а в порядке выполнения

Comment: я не знаю, да, по этому в первом предложении есть вопрос к вам о том что делает if. что я точно знаю, так это 2 вещи - использование if в контекст location обычно плохая практика (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) и то, что 80% кейсов с if легко меняются на вычисление в map

Comment: @nörbörnën вы понимаете, что вопрос не об использовании `if` а про порядок выполнения? Вы понимаете, что для порядка выполнения неважно что находится в `if`? Вы пытаетесь "уточнить" то, что никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет

Comment: map вычислится при "поступлении" запроса и не нужно будет думать о порядке выполнения

Comment: @nörbörnën вы же сами писали про "80% кейсов" - все if-ы на map не заменишь, так что вопрос по-прежнему актуален

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конфигурация nginx это не «программа» которая выполняется сверху вниз. Порядок директив в общем случае не влияет на порядок обработки запроса. За редким исключением, самое важное из которых модуль `mod_rewrite` в котором, в частности, и определена директива `if` (а так же `rewrite` и ещё парочка). Но даже в этом случае порядок в конфигурации влияет только на директивы из этого модуля.

Т.е.

```
set $a 1;
if ($a) { ... }
```

и

```
if ($a) { ... }
set $a 1;
```

выполнятся по разному, но

```
proxy_pass http://upstream;
if ($a) { ... }
```

и

```
if ($a) { ... }
proxy_pass http://upstream;
```

для nginx ничем не отличаются.

Далее, nginx обрабатывает запрос по [фазам](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) и каждая директива относится к какой-то фазе. Директива `location` обрабатывается в фазе поиска блока (`NGX_HTTP_FIND_CONFIG_PHASE`) в котором надо обрабатывать запрос, а `if` в фазе rewrite (`NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE`) найденного блока.

Т.е. в вашем примере всегда сначала «выполнится» `location` и если был запрос на `/alpha/bravo`, то директива `if` не выполниться вообще, т.к. запрос обрабатывается блоком `location /alpha/bravo`, а не блоком `location /alpha`.

Если запрос был по адресу `/alpha/charlie`, то `if` выполниться, а что там внутри `location /alpha/bravo` nginx-у вообще неважно.